# Ayuda con este error php consulta between

Tags: php

```
<form method="_POST">
    <p>Busqueda</p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="busca1" id="busca1">
    </p>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value"buscar">
    </label>
</form>
<?php
    $busca="";
    $busca1="";
    $busca=$_POST['busca'];
    $busca1=$_POST['busca1'];
    $conexion= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,'premios_bd');
    if($busca!="" && $busca1!=""){
        $busqueda=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ganador Where N_acta BETWEEN '$busca' AND '$busca1'");
        while($f=mysql_fech_arrar($busqueda)){
            echo $f['Item'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$f['Nombres']."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Tengo este codigo para hacer una consulta a la bd mysql con una consulta between pero me bota el siguiente error a la hora de abrir la web:

> Notice: Undefined index: busca in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: busca1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php on line 17

Comment: Bienvenido!. Añade el código de tu archivo tres.php

Comment: cambia la primera linea por esto <form method="POST" action="">

Comment: Leonardo lo cambie pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Prueba así:  <form method="POST"> o así <form method="POST" action="tres.php">

Comment: Si escribes un `var_dump($_POST);` al principio del todo, antes de declarar `$busca`... imprime algo?

Comment: creo que te hace falta validar `if ($_POST)` y luego entre a esa funcion en la linea de la busca hasta el final del query

Comment: track3r no me funciono ninguna de las 2 alternativas.

Comment: pregunta , por que el method es `_POST`?

Comment: He reproducido exactamente tu formulario, aún dejando esto así: `<form method="_POST">` y funciona sin problemas. A mi me parece que no estás en el archivo que crees estar, o que debes limpiar el caché de tu navegador. ¿El archivo del código que muestras se llama `tres.php` seguro, y la URL a la que accedes es a la ese archivo, a o otro archivo llamado `tres.php` que está en otra carpeta?

Comment: Si estaba en un error ahora cuando hago la consulta a la bd me ocurre esto 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php on line 31

alguna idea?

Comment: Tu debes utilizar mysqli_query ya que estas utilizando la conexión con mysqli_connect

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha realizado ya en [numerosas ocasiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Notice%3A+Undefined+index) y tiene respuesta en el sitio. Por favor, lee [ask] y sigue los consejos que encontrarás allí y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y cómo funciona en general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema esta en que cuando carga la página estas intentando recoger por post los valores, que realmente no llegan. La forma correcta es detectar cuando el usuario envia ese formulario, para eso utilizamos la función isset.

```
<form method="POST">
<p> Busqueda</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="busca1" id="busca1">
</p>
<label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value"buscar">
</label>
</form>
```

Codigo PHP.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $busca="";

        $busca1="";

        $busca=$_POST['busca'];

        $busca1=$_POST['busca1'];


        $conexion= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

        mysqli_select_db($conexion,'premios_bd');

        if($busca!="" && $busca1!=""){

            $busqueda=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ganador Where N_acta BETWEEN '$busca' AND '$busca1'");

            while($f=mysql_fech_arrar($busqueda)){
                echo $f['Item'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$f['Nombres']."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Eugeni me corrio perfecto pero ahora cuando hago la consulta de que deseo me bota este error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tres.php on line 31

alguna idea del porque?

Comment: Te recomiendo iniciar otra pregunta porque se trataría de otro error diferente y de paso, elije la respuesta que solucionó el error de la pregunta inicial y acéptala para que otros usuarios con tu mismo problema (la pregunta), tengan una solución al alcance.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías constatar primero si los post están seteados, la primera vez que cargas la página no vienen los post 'busca' y 'busca1'.

```
if (isset($_POST['busca']) && isset($_POST['busca1']){
```

Además en el while está mal escrito el fetch

```
while($f=mysql_fech_arrar($busqueda)){
```

cambiar por

```
while($f=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
```